# xcode 9 linker error with kingfisher 3.13.1

Tags: swift, xcode9, kingfisher

I just upgraded to xcode 9, my project fails when linking kingfisher with below linker error.
I tried cleaning pod cache, reinstalling all pod files, explicitly setting swift language to 3.2 in all pods, nothing worked.

> ld:
>   /Users/haha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-awwowqdhnsdvouehdfyrbrdxrhdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kingfisher/Kingfisher.framework/Kingfisher
>   compiled with newer version of Swift language (4.0) than previous
>   files (3.0) file
>   '/Users/haha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-awwowqdhnsdvouehdfyrbrdxrhdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kingfisher/Kingfisher.framework/Kingfisher'
>   for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Below is the Podfile

```
target 'myproject' do

  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myproject

  pod 'PlugNPlay', '~> 1.1.0'

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'

  pod 'GoogleMaps'

  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.13.1'

  pod 'CitrusGraphics', '~> 1.1.2'

  pod 'CitrusPay', '~> 4.1.6'

  target 'myprojectTests' do

inherit! :search_paths

# Pods for testing
end

post_install do |installer|

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

    if target.name == 'Kingfisher'

        target.build_configurations.each do |config|

            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'

        end

    end

end

end

end
```

Comment: I've got the same issue. Have no idea where the swift 4 version is coming from.

Comment: How did you guys get over it???